# Grabbing the UIPasteboard like Pastebot while running in the background

Tags: iphone, url, notifications, multitasking, uipasteboard

I know this is possible as Tapbots Pastebot does this. I am trying to grab the UIPasteboard when my iPhone app is running in the background and add it to a UITableView just as Pastebot does but I am also trying to shorten the link, if its a URL and copy that back to the UIPastboard so its ready for the user to paste anywhere. Now Pastebot apparently runs in the background by playing an audio file for 10 minutes. I have set up the NSNotificationCenter like so in the applicationDidFinishLaunching

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pasteboardChangedNotification:) name:UIPasteboardChangedNotification object:[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pasteboardChangedNotification:) name:UIPasteboardRemovedNotification object:[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]];

- (void)pasteboardChangedNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
pasteboardChangeCount_ = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].changeCount; 
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
     if (pasteboardChangeCount_ != [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].changeCount) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UIPasteboardChangedNotification object:[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]];
     }
}
```

Can anyone point me in a direction on grabbing the UIPasteboard and shortening a link, if its a URL and sending it back to the UIPasteboard? I have read the multitasking dev documents and the UIPasteboard documents. If anyone has a solution can you please share them with me?

Thanks

Comment: How on earth did Pastebot get on the appstore?

Comment: Apparently, this trick doesn't violate any of the App Store rules. It doesn't use private API's so I would gather as they do, its 100% safe. Its too bad they won't share their trick.

Comment: Last I heard, they have a time limit of 10 minutes. Not infringing anything. All I can think of is when in the background, each time the UIPasteboard changes, then grab the object...

Comment: I've tried everything I could think of. Hopefully this can be achieved. I doubt Tapbots would share their secret.

Comment: Maybe try and contact them, always give it a try ;)

Comment: I can't imagine that Apple are happy about them misusing the background audio API. I would have thought there'd be a clause stating that multitasking APIs must be used for their intended purposes. Someone could create an app that connects to their own server for shortening urls, and then after the app is accepted mess round with the server so that it returns urls to malicious sites (or porn).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I have managed to achieve something similar is by not bothering with the `NSNotificationCenter` and instead just copying the contents of the `UIPasteboard` at regular intervals whilst in the background.

The code bellow checks the `UIPasteboard` once a second for a thousand seconds.  I believe that an application can run in the background for around 10 minutes without playing audio. If you play an audio file in the background the application can keep running.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Create a background task identifier
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task; 
    task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"System terminated background task early"); 
        [application endBackgroundTask:task];
    }];

    // If the system refuses to allow the task return
    if (task == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
    {
        NSLog(@"System refuses to allow background task");
        return;
    }

    // Do the task
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

        NSString *pastboardContents = nil;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
        {
            if (![pastboardContents isEqualToString:[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string]) 
            {
                pastboardContents = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string;
                NSLog(@"Pasteboard Contents: %@", pastboardContents);
            }

            // Wait some time before going to the beginning of the loop
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
        }

        // End the task
        [application endBackgroundTask:task];
    });


}
```

Answer (score 4):

Tapbots actually wrote an entry on their blog a few months back about the trick they use to get at the clipboard in the background. I don't use the app myself, so I can't verify that this ever came to fruition, but here's the relevant [blog entry](http://tapbots.com/blog/pastebot/pastebot-music-in-background).

Comment: I did read it, was very interesting. I have given that a try but it didn't work. They have to be using task completion but I've tried that and still didn't get it to work.

Comment: Hi there, link to **Tapbot**'s blog entry is dead, any resurrection stone available for a fellow developer? Thanks ;-)

Comment: Apple ended up cracking down on the method the blog post used — playing a silent audio file as a way to keep the app running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of an old thread. But I'd like to share this with you:

http://blog.daanraman.com/coding/monitor-the-ios-pasteboard-while-running-in-the-background/#comment-15135

However, I have my doubts whether Apple will reject this when trying to submit it to the App Store, as it feels to me like a hack. A hack that Apple tries hard to avoid with its whole background multitasking thing.

Anyone thoughts about it?