# How can I listen the system copy event on iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa

I saw there is a programme like this:

http://vimeo.com/44396882

The programme can listen to the iOS's copy event, and blind the information to the programme? How the programme actually doing in the background? Thanks.

Comment: This has been answered here on stackoverflow before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721733/grabbing-the-uipasteboard-like-pastebot-while-running-in-the-background

Answer (score -1):

I assume you're referring to the user copying text, right? Well you can't hijack the device so that your application receives these events wherever the user is, but you **can** listen to this events while the user is using your app by registering for the `"UIPasteboardChangedNotification"` notification.

If this notification is posted while you're app is in the background, it should receive it once it's back in the foreground. I assumed this from:

[image]

More info [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html)

Comment: Please do not paste screenshots of documentation into your answer.  Copy the text, as text.  This is bad for several different reasons (readability, search ability, bandwidth, etc.).